# pandas df.resample('D').sum() returns NaN

Tags: pandas, nan

I've got a pandas data frame with electricity meter readings(cumulative). The df DatetimeIndex  dtype='datetime64[ns]'. When I load the .csv file the dataframe does not contain any NaN values. I need to calculate both the monthly and daily energy generated.

To calculate monthly generation I use dfmonth = df.resample('M').sum() . This works fine.
To calculate daily generation I thought of using: dfday = df.resample('D').sum(). Which partially works but for some index dates (no data missing in raw file) returns NaN.

Please see code below. Does anyone knows why this happens? Any proposed solution?

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Reading Timestamp']))
df=df.rename(columns = {'Energy kWh':'meter', 'Instantaneous Power kW (approx)': 'kW'})
df.drop(df.columns[:10], axis=1, inplace=True) #Delete columns I don't need.
df['kWh'] = df['meter'].sub(df['meter'].shift())
dfmonth = df.resample('M').sum() #This works OK calculating kWh. dfmonth does not contain any NaN.
dfday = df.resample('D').sum() # This returns a total of 8 NaN out of 596 sampled points. Original df has 27929 DatetimeIndex rows
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you missing dates in your index? e.g. perhaps you don't have entries for weekend dates?

Comment: No, I am not missing any dates. I can attach the .csv if that helps

Comment: Please attach your raw data and code to reproduce your data, my point is are you missing dates for specific days? If you look at your `NaN` entries are these because you don't have any index entries containing those dates? This is probably what's happening

Answer (score 0):

A big apology to you all. The .csv I was given and the raw .csv I was checking against are not the same file. Data was somehow corrupted....
I've been banging my head against the wall till now, there is not problem with df.resample('D').sum()

Sorry again, consider thread sorted.